# Obtaining tags from AWS instances with boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, instances

I'm trying to obtain tags from instances in my AWS account using Python's boto library.

While this snippet works correctly bringing all tags:

```
    tags = e.get_all_tags()
    for tag in tags:
        print tag.name, tag.value
```

(e is an EC2 connection)

When I request tags from individual instances,

```
    print vm.__dict__['tags']
```

or

```
    print vm.tags
```

I'm getting an empty list (vm is actually an instance class).

The following code:

```
    vm.__dict__['tags']['Name']
```

of course results in:

```
KeyError: 'Name'
```

My code was working until yesterday and suddenly I'm not able to get the tags from an instance.

Does anybody know whether there is a problem with AWS API?

Comment: You say that ``vm`` is an ``instance class``.  I'm not sure what that means.  Could you do ``type(vm)`` and post the result here?

Comment: Sorry for misleading. In boto, there is a class called "instance" that represents an AWS instance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to be sure that the 'Name' tag exists before accessing it. Try this:

```
import boto.ec2
conn=boto.ec2.connect_to_region("eu-west-1")
reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
for res in reservations:
    for inst in res.instances:
        if 'Name' in inst.tags:
            print "%s (%s) [%s]" % (inst.tags['Name'], inst.id, inst.state)
        else:
            print "%s [%s]" % (inst.id, inst.state)
```

will print:

```
i-4e444444 [stopped]
Amazon Linux (i-4e333333) [running]
```

Comment: Boto now has the ability to get instances directly -- ```instances = self._ec2_connection.get_only_instances()``` -- http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.get_only_instances

Comment: I think this answer could be put in a cleaner and more understandable way. It's the closest thing to an answer for a similar question and after reading it a half dozen times I'm still puzzling about how tags work.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
import boto.ec2

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2')
# Find a specific instance, returns a list of Reservation objects
reservations = conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=['i-xxxxxxxx'])
# Find the Instance object inside the reservation
instance = reservations[0].instances[0]
print(instance.tags)
```

You should see all tags associated with instance `i-xxxxxxxx` printed out.

Comment: This is what I did. I got he list of reservations and then the list of instances in the reservation. When I print tags I see an empty list "{}". The weird is that I run the same code with another AWS account and I can see all tags for an instance. It seems a problem with my first AWS account.

Comment: It turned out to be an error in my code. There was one instance without the tag "Name" and my code was trying to get this tag from every instance. Thus I got: KeyError: 'Name'. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Currently its: `conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=['i-xxxx'])`
Compared to: `conn.get_all_instances(instance_id=['i-xxxx'])` Argument needs to be plural

Answer (score 1):

For boto3 you will need to do this.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
vpc = ec2.Vpc('<your vpc id goes here>')
instance_iterator = vpc.instances.all()

for instance in instance_iterator:
    for tag in instance.tags:
        print('Found instance id: ' + instance.id + '\ntag: ' + tag)
```

Comment: How can i get public IP's tags which aren't in VPC ?

Comment: The docs are here: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html You may need something like ClassicAddress.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an error in my code. I did not consider the case of having one instance without the tag 'Name'.

There was one instance without the tag "Name" and my code was trying to get this tag from every instance.

When I ran this piece of code in an instance without the tag 'Name',

```
vm.__dict__['tags']['Name']
```

I got: KeyError: 'Name'. vm is a AWS instance.
With the instances that actually had this tag set, I didn't have any problem.

Thank you for your help and sorry for asking when it was only my own mistake.