# Displaying EC2 Instance name using Boto 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm not sure how to display the name of my instance in AWS EC2 using `boto3`

This is some of the code I have:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')
vpc = ec2.Vpc("vpc-21c15555")
for i in vpc.instances.all():
    print(i)
```

What I get in return is

```
...
...
...
ec2.Instance(id='i-d77ed20c')
```

[image]

I can change `i` to be `i.id` or `i.instance_type` but when I try `name` I get:

`AttributeError: 'ec2.Instance' object has no attribute 'name'`

What is the correct way to get the instance name?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There may be other ways. But from your code point of view, the following should work.

```
>>> for i in vpc.instances.all():
...   for tag in i.tags:
...     if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
...       print tag['Value']
```

One liner solution if you want to use Python's powerful list comprehension:

```
inst_names = [tag['Value'] for i in vpc.instances.all() for tag in i.tags if tag['Key'] == 'Name']
print inst_names
```

Answer (score 7):

In AWS EC2 an instance is *tagged* with a Name [tag](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html).

In order to get the value of the Name tag for a given instance, you need to query the instance for that tag:

See [Obtaining tags from AWS instances with boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516678/obtaining-tags-from-aws-instances-with-boto)