# Do ec2 tag numbers change?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Below is some simple code. What SHOULD pull the key:name tag. However when I add a second tag, it seems to change the order, so 0 isn't always the name???

```
instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name':'instance-state-name','Values':['running']}])
    for instance in instances:
        for tag in instance.tags:
            if 'Name'in tag['Key']:
                name = tag['Value']
    print "Pulling all instance info..."
    for instance in instances:
        print(instance.id, instance.instance_type,instance.private_ip_address, instance.tags[0].get("Value"))
```

Comment: what do you mean by `tag numbers`? If you want unique identifier for your instance, use `instance id`. It remains the same and is unique per instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `instance.tags` is a list and your tag can appear anywhere in the list. If you are trying to get the 'Name', you have to loop through the list. Each element in the list is a dictionary. Check if the key is 'Name' before getting the value.

It sounds complex, but very simple to code. You cannot blindly do `instance.tags[0].get("Value")`

Comment: Ah. So 0 will only work if there is one tag. Got it. Any idea what this would look like correctly?

Comment: Something similar to this. See my answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751794/displaying-ec2-instance-name-using-boto-3

Comment: So I tried this, and using the example listed it leave the variable as the last instance name (nametag = instread of print).

Comment: convert the list to a dictionary and access the tag by name