# boto3 error unable to get tags for instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Trying to get this code working. I want to get the tags of the instances in my vpc. I got the code from here ([Displaying EC2 Instance name using Boto 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751794/displaying-ec2-instance-name-using-boto-3))

```
import boto3
import boto3.ec2

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

#for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
#    print(bucket.name)
#

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-1')
vpc = ec2.Vpc("vpc-59d5d73d")
for i in vpc.instances.all():
  for tag in i.tags:
    if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
      print tag['Value']
```

I used the S3 code just to make sure that I installed and configured boto correctly and it did indeed return the buckets in my account.

My problem is when I run the code below I get:

```
python botoGetTags.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "botoGetTags.py", line 9, in <module>
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 92, in resource
    return _get_default_session().resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 389, in resource
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 263, in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 818, in create_client
    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 62, in create_client
    service_model = self._load_service_model(service_name, api_version)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 92, in _load_service_model
    api_version=api_version)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/loaders.py", line 123, in _wrapper
    data = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/loaders.py", line 358, in load_service_model
    return self.load_data(full_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/loaders.py", line 123, in _wrapper
    data = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/loaders.py", line 382, in load_data
    raise DataNotFoundError(data_path=name)
```

I'm just lost on where to look for the fix to this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked fine for me!

I suggest you check that you are running the latest version of boto:

```
sudo pip install boto3 --upgrade --ignore six

Successfully installed boto3-1.4.1 botocore-1.4.61 docutils-0.12 futures-3.0.5 jmespath-0.9.0 python-dateutil-2.5.3 s3transfer-0.1.7 six-1.10.0
```

Comment: that was it! what does --ignore six do? I did the install according to the manual `pip install boto3`

Comment: Something uses the `six` library, and it is now deprecated (or at least I often get errors). So, I find that specifically excluding it helps the upgrade succeed.