# If I just wanted to get EC2 instances whose value of tag's env is "dev" , how should I modify code based on this script?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[This script let me get all instances]

[How Can I use Python dictionary Grouping AWS instances by tag's name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024460/how-can-i-use-python-dictionary-grouping-aws-instances-by-tags-name)

When I run the script in this link :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf8 -*-

import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-1')
reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
InstanceMap={}
for reservation in reservations:
    for instance in reservation.instances:
        if 'Name' in instance.tags:
            tag_name = instance.tags['Name']
            if tag_name in InstanceMap:
                InstanceMap[tag_name].append(instance.id)
            else:
                InstanceMap[tag_name] = [instance.id,]
```

I get all EC2 Instances ID and Instances tag's name.

The result is

```
{'ap1-dev': ['i-04ebd1403d93bef01'],

 'ap1-prod': ['i-08f0c8a3f495bad71', 'i-0508a3800cd0ec331'],

 'ap1-stage': ['i-0716b2fd4089c7471', 'i-025002d2da8396171'],

 'ap2-dev': ['i-08ffb39676b7b1c81'],

 'ap2-prod': ['i-019dbf70c2f061521', 'i-0d2d482cb85419131'],

 'ap2-stage': ['i-04d71424b7257b4b1', 'i-02c0046baae635d31']}
```

The value of instance tags's name is ap1-dev , the value of its tags's env is dev

The value of instacne tags's name is ap1-prod, the value of its tags's env is prod

Now My question is :

If I just wanted to get EC2 instances whose value of tag's env is "dev" .
The result I want to get is this :

```
{'ap1-dev': ['i-04ebd1403d93bef01'],

 'ap2-dev': ['i-08ffb39676b7b1c81']}
```

How should I modify code based on this script?

Answer (score 1):

You want to consider the tags which end with `-dev`.

Change this line:

```
if 'Name' in instance.tags:
```

to:

```
if 'Name' in instance.tags and instance.tags['Name'].endswith('-dev'):
```

You can also make this as a method and pass your "environment" like `dev`, `prod`, `stage` instead of modifying code each time.

Comment: Thanks Very much !  I use this line:                                                                
    if 'Name' in instance.tags and 'env' in instance.tags and instance.tags['env'] == 'stage'                                                                                                                      is  successful.